# How can I convert a pickle file to JSON format?

Tags: python, json, pickle

I have a pickle file needs to be converted to a json format , I used this code

```
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    from sys import argv
    
    script, filename = argv
    input_file = open('f.pkl', 'rb')
    new_dict = pickle.load(input_file)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient='index')
    df['index1'] = df.index
    index1 = df['index1']
    df.drop(labels=['index1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.insert(0, 'index1', index1)
    json_df = df.to_json(orient='values', date_format='iso', date_unit='s')
    with open('data.json', 'w') as js_file:
        js_file.write(json_df)
```

but got

```
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient='index')
  File "pandas/core/frame.py", line 1127, in from_dict
    if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: You must run this script from command line with the appropriate filename argument.

Comment: It seems that the pickled object is a list and not a dictionary.

Comment: yes it is a list and i tried to convert it to JSON .. is there any other solution

Answer (score 0):

The line df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient='index') is the error. According to the error, you're trying to load from a pickle file which is a list, not a dictionary: the result from `new_dict = pickle.load(input_file)` is a list (it could be any kind of data structure). Try to add `isinstance()` to check whether the unpickled data is a list or a dictionary.

For example mine was dataFrame, and for that I used this code in Python:

```
import json
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# opens the pickle file
with open('changewithyours.pickle', 'rb') as input_file:
    # loads the pickle file into a pandas DataFrame
    data = pd.read_pickle(input_file)

# resets the index of the DataFrame
data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# converts the DataFrame to JSON and write it to a file
data.to_json('data.json', orient='columns')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).